# Vinegar on Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven

Is white distilled Vinegar Ok to own on Pesach?

Many products list vinegar as an ingredient such as Ketchup, mayonnaise, salad dressings etc..
Are they ok to own on pesach?

http://www.crcweb.org/Passover/What%20is%20Chametz%20(DC).pdf

The question seems to be if we can rely on the fact most distilled vinegar is made from an alcohol fermented from corn and not wheat.

Another question is white distilled vinegar *fit for dog eating*? Its never consumed by itself.

Comment: Heinz only uses corn. I asked them.

Comment: Yeah. Thats what they say on their website http://www.heinzvinegar.com/vinegar-101.aspx

Comment: The [OU Passover Guide](http://oukosher.org/passover/articles/which-foods-are-chametz-2/) has the same article (in an easier to search and read format) which explicitly says that one may rely on Rov to consider it kitniyos. It also seems to say that even though white distilled vinegar is never used on its own, the fact that it is an ingredient in ketchup (for example) in the way that it is means that it is not considered aino ra'ui la'acholas kelev.

Comment: Thanks. I read that article and I wasn't sure what to make of it. If we can rely on the fact that its Kitniyot why do they recommend selling it?

Comment: [star-k](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-palate-vinegar.htm) does not deal with Rov but explicitly says that one must check if the original source is chametz or kitniyos (as the heinz vinegar web site says). However, all the articles imply that the question of 'not fit for a dog' does not arise as the vinegar is definitely chametz or kitniyos.

Comment: @Michael Horowitz If it is not definite that it is kitniyos, then we should not rely on assumptions. For example, even if we know that something is kitniyos, it could have a sufficient mixture of chametz with it to require it to be sold. Since people do not want to take the slightest chance of making a misteak [sic] they will sell the product containing the vinegar "just in case". Relying on rov (majority) is an after the fact (bediavad) situation and not lechatchilah.

Comment: @MichaelHorwitz The significant line in the article is "Therefore, since there isn’t any reasonable way for the average consumer to figure out whether the vinegar in their ketchup (for example) is chametz, they may rely on the [Rov] (majority) and assume that the vinegar is not chametz at least to the extent that it may/should be sold to a non-Jew. " However one should not rely on the assumption in order to keep ownership of it. The consequences of a mistake are too great

Comment: @sabbahillel "Relying on rov (majority) is an after the fact (bediavad) situation and not lechatchilah." This is after the fact. You already own the vinegar.